# Is it possible to set a Sphere as a Fluid Simulation Domain?

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

This what happens when I try it...

[image]

I'm using Blender v3.6.2

Comment: as you already tested - no. Just use a normal cube as domain and use a sphere as effector to get this effect.

Comment: I tried that plenty too, doesn't work

Comment: of course that works. Provide a blend file where you tried that, i will then show you what you have to change, that i works